# Не рисует в Win32Api?

Tags: c++, winapi, keydown

Вот код:

```
 sx = LOWORD(lParam); //Ширина окна
 sy = HIWORD(lParam); //Высота окна
 a = sx / 2; //Координаты
 b = sy / 2; //центра окна
 h = 3 * M_PI / a; //Шаг по оси х

MoveToEx(hdc, 0, b, NULL);
for (x = -M_PI, x_scr = y_scr = 0; x < M_PI; x += h)
    {
        x_scr = ((x + M_PI)*a / M_PI);
        y_scr = (grafik('2', x, y_scr, b));
        LineTo(hdc, x_scr, y_scr);
    }

    int grafik(char c, double x, int y_scr, int b)
{
    switch (c)
{
case '1':
    return y_scr = b * (1 - tan(x));
case '2':
    return y_scr = b * (1 - sin(x));
case '3':
    return y_scr = b * (1 - cos(x));
case '4':
    return y_scr = x;
case '5':
    return y_scr = x*x;
case '6':
    return y_scr = sqrt(x);
}
}
```

С помощью кода рисуется один из графиков который запрашивает пользователь, и рисует, но как только я пихаю его в `swith` он прекращает рисовать.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch (wParam) {
    case VK_ESCAPE:
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        break;
    case VK_NUMPAD1:

        sx = LOWORD(lParam); //Ширина окна
        sy = HIWORD(lParam); //Высота окна
        a = sx / 2; //Координаты
        b = sy / 2; //центра окна
        h = 3 * M_PI / a; //Шаг по оси х

        MoveToEx(hdc, 0, b, NULL);
        for (x = -M_PI, x_scr = y_scr = 0; x < M_PI; x += h)
        {
            x_scr = ((x + M_PI)*a / M_PI);
            y_scr = (grafik('2', x, y_scr, b));
            LineTo(hdc, x_scr, y_scr);
        }

        break;
    }
    break;


case WM_PAINT: 
    switch (wParam) {
    case VK_NUMPAD1:

    sx = LOWORD(lParam); //Ширина окна
    sy = HIWORD(lParam); //Высота окна
    a = sx / 2; //Координаты
    b = sy / 2; //центра окна
    h = 3 * M_PI / a; //Шаг по оси х

    MoveToEx(hdc, 0, b, NULL);
    for (x = -M_PI, x_scr = y_scr = 0; x < M_PI; x += h)
    {
        x_scr = ((x + M_PI)*a / M_PI);
        y_scr = (grafik('2', x, y_scr, b));
        LineTo(hdc, x_scr, y_scr);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Рисовать надо в ответ на сообщение `WM_PAINT`, а не на `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: И там тоже не рисует!(

Comment: Приведите код с `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: @D-side Обновил вопрос

Comment: А какие, по-вашему, параметры у события `WM_PAINT`? :)

Comment: @D-side Тогда, можете подсказать как мне сделать прорисовку по нажатию клавиши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я буду говорить о C, но не думаю, что это сильно меняет дело.

`lParam` и `wParam` это параметры, передаваемые от ОС приложению. И они имеют разный смысл в зависимости от типа события. Проверять "что за клавиша" в событии рисования нельзя, а значит, нужно сообщить в событие рисования нужные данные самостоятельно из других.

Вам нужно где-то хранить "состояние приложения". События ввода будут его изменять, а события вывода на него опираться. Выбор хранилища за вами: это может быть структура или набор переменных, статическая переменная в функции или глобальная (а если затрагивать C++, это может быть поле в классе). Важно, чтобы она была доступна для чтения и записи из любого места вашего обработчика событий.

Comment: А почему бы не вызвать перерисовку формы просто из нажатия клавиши?

Comment: Перерисовку, в смысле `InvalidateRect`?

Comment: @Qwertiy это не отменяет того, что непосредственные команды рисования должны быть в обработке `WM_PAINT`. `InvalidateRect` это задействование "состояния приложения", хранящегося в ОС. Вариант, да.